# Tootlip inside TextField helperText when error is true

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield, tooltip

I have a TextField like that:

```
          <TextField
            label='שם סקופ'
            onChange={(e) => onChangeValue('scopeName', e.target.value)}
            error={error.scopeNameError !== ''}
            helperText={error.scopeNameError}
          />
```

For now I only display some message if the input is incorrect, but I want to add a tooltip there so I can give the user instructions of what to do. I tried followed the mui documentation but when I added the tooltip it broke the element and written over the next TextField like shown in the picture [here](https://ibb.co/HFwBnt4)

This is the code I wrote which have broken:

```
<TextField
        label='שם סקופ'
        onChange={(e) => onChangeValue('scopeName', e.target.value)}
         error={error.scopeNameError !== ''}
         helperText={
          error.scopeNameError !== '' ? (
           <Tooltip title='שם סקופ אסור להכין תווים מיוחדים או רק מספרים'>
               <Button>{error.scopeNameError}</Button>
           </Tooltip>) : (error.scopeNameError)
     }/>
```

Comment: Seems like an odd use of a Button. What if you just put scopeNameError inside a span instead? See https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-hill-x4cesq?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Where exactly do you want the tooltip to show?

Comment: If my csb doesn't work for you, try this link instead: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1yebj8-zncr2a?file=demo.tsx

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked and I just added margin so there'll be enough space between each input